# cakephp dropdown with id assigned to each option

Tags: cakephp, html-select

I have to create dropdown with id assigned to each option as
my array is

```
array(
    (int) 0 =>array(
              'Student'=>array(
                         'id'    => '1',
                         'name'  => 'abc',
                         'class' => 'c1',
                         )
              ),
   (int) 1 =>array(
              'Student'=>array(
                         'id'    => '2',
                         'name'  => 'def',
                         'class' => 'c2',
                         )
              ),

);
```

and html should be

```
<select>
  <option id='c1' value='1'>abc</option>
  <option id='c2' value='2'>def</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is resolved as

```
         foreach($students as $student){
                    $options[] = array(
                        'id' => $student['Students']['class'],
                        'value'=>$student['Students']['id'],
                        'name' => $student['Students']['name']
                    );
         echo $this->Form->input('students', array('options' => $options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an options array with your custom attributes.

```
$options = array();
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $options[] = array(
        'id' => $student['Student']['class'],
        'value' => $student['Student']['id'],
        'name' => $student['Student']['name']
    );
}

echo $this->Form->input('student_id', array('options' => $options));
```

Comment: Don't forget the `value` key (that's where `$student['Student']['id']` should go), [**it won't work properly without it**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.7/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2733).

Comment: I do not want to replace value with ID, I want to have ID, VALUE and HTML text.